# IntersectionObserver for items in carousel

Tags: intersection-observer

The visibility detection of the first and last item in the carousel does not work for me.
This is my function:

```
function(rootEl) {
    var wrapEl = rootEl.closest('.db_carousel_wrap');
    var productEl = rootEl.querySelector('.db_product');
    var previousEl = wrapEl.querySelector('.db_previous_button');
    var nextEl = wrapEl.querySelector('.db_next_button');
    var maxScrollLeft = rootEl.scrollWidth - rootEl.clientWidth;
    previousEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (rootEl.scrollLeft > 0) {
            rootEl.scrollLeft -= productEl.clientWidth;
        }
    });
    nextEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (rootEl.scrollLeft !== maxScrollLeft) {
            rootEl.scrollLeft += productEl.clientWidth;
        }
    });
    nextEl.classList.remove('pointer-events-none');
    nextEl.classList.remove('bg-grayLighter');
    nextEl.classList.add('bg-black');
    var observerLeftArrow = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
        entries.forEach(function(entry) {
            console.log(entry);
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                previousEl.classList.add('pointer-events-none');
                previousEl.classList.add('bg-grayLighter');
                previousEl.classList.remove('bg-black');
            } else {
                previousEl.classList.remove('pointer-events-none');
                previousEl.classList.remove('bg-grayLighter');
                previousEl.classList.add('bg-black');
            }
        });
    });
    var leftElement = rootEl.querySelector('.db_product:nth-child(1)');
    observerLeftArrow.observe(leftElement, {
        root: wrapEl
    });
    var observerRightArrow = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
        entries.forEach(function(entry) {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                nextEl.classList.add('pointer-events-none');
                nextEl.classList.add('bg-grayLighter');
                nextEl.classList.remove('bg-black');
            } else {
                nextEl.classList.remove('pointer-events-none');
                nextEl.classList.remove('bg-grayLighter');
                nextEl.classList.add('bg-black');
            }
        });
    });
    var rightElement = rootEl.querySelector('.db_product:last-child');
    observerRightArrow.observe(rightElement, {
        root: wrapEl
    });
};
```

After the first scroll, I can no longer see the first item, but the function has evaluated that it is possible.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fatap.png)

Root selector doesn't help me, not even margin